# How to access MS SQL Server Data Web Using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, remote-desktop

I'm thinking of an alternative to remote the database of my server.
Is it possible via web?
Like the picture below.
[image: SQL Server Online]

Wanna ask how to create this one on PHP or if there is already open source exist.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org/) to access MS SQL data.